# DNS response answer & authoritative section

Tags: dns, response, wireshark, web-traffic, network-traffic

I have been looking at DNS response packets in Wireshark, and am not able to understand hex coding for the answer and authoritative sections.

Considering DNS query for: mail.abcd.com

The answer section contains name field, and the hex coding for this varies among:

```
 0xc00c
 0xc012
```

Both of them lead to the entire name being populated in the field.

The authoritative section also contains the name field, but the hex coding for this is usually:

```
 0xc010
```

This leads to abcd.com being populated in the field.

Can anyone tell what is the convention followed to populate these fields, as its pretty confusing.

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully useful: http://www.zoneedit.com/doc/rfc/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DNS labels use a format of `<length><data ...>`.

A label may be a maximum of 63 bytes long, hence the `<length>` field has two bits left over.  These are used to encode a label type.

If the top two bits are `0b11` then the remaining six bits are instead combined with the following byte form a *compression pointer* which is an offset within the DNS payload to a *prior* instance of another label.

Since the DNS protocol header is 12 bytes long, the shortest legal offset is 12 bytes, giving the value you saw above of `0xc00c`.

[*technically*, one might construct a compression pointer that points into the header, but it's not strictly conformant with the protocol].

I would strongly recommend *against* trying to reverse engineer the specification from wire packets - you will inevitably miss stuff.  Just read [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) instead - all of the core stuff is in there.

Comment: But what if an implementation does not comply with the standard? Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but the receiver _should_ treat it as a malformed response

Answer (score 5):

Read up on [name compression](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4.1.4) in the specification. 0xc, 0x12, and 0x10 are pointers to earlier copies of the names "mail.abcd.com" and "abcd.com" in the packet.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Name Compression technique from DNS]

DNS messages use an **offset value** to say how many bytes after the beginning of the message we can find the domain name already included in the message.

[image]

Where the “address of the beginning byte” is counted in bytes from the beginning of the entire message. **Start counting with zero as the first byte**.

So in our example 0xC00C is 1100 0000 0000 1100 which means 1100 offset which is 12 bytes from the **beginning of the entire DNS message**.